# Continuing to the next value in a foreach not working as expected

Tags: c#

What I am trying to accomplish is to leave a `for each` loop once a counter has been reached, then move on to the next item in the array, my code so far is:

Code:

```
if (keywordUsed == "PARSE_ALL")
{
    string keyword = GetKeywords();
    string[] words = keyword.Split('|');

    int pageParse = 6;
    int pageCount = 0;

    // Loop all the keywords one at a time.
    foreach (string word in words) {

        LoadUrl("https://google.com/");

        await SearchEngineDelay(5000);
        var script = @"document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = '" + GetProperSearchReady(word) + "'; document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click();";
        chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        await SearchEngineDelay(5000);

        if (txtBoxHtmlSourceCode.Text.Contains("It looks like there aren't many great matches for your search"))
        {
            BtnFindPotentialLinks.Enabled = true;
            return;
        }

        ExtractLinksFromWebPage(await GetHtmlAsncAsync(chromeBrowser), word, "google.com");

        await SearchEngineDelay(5000);

        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateLinksCount()));
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => UpdateKeywordBeingUsed(word)));

        string[] googleSearchPages = { "document.querySelector('#xjs > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) > a').click()",
                                "document.querySelector('#xjs > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4) > a').click()",
                                "document.querySelector('#xjs > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5) > a').click()",
                                "document.querySelector('#xjs > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6) > a').click()",
                                "document.querySelector('#xjs > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(7) > a').click()",
                                "document.querySelector('#xjs > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(8) > a').click()"
                                };

        foreach (var scriptToExecute in googleSearchPages)
        {
            pageCount++;
            //ClassHelpers.ReturnMessage(pageCount + " -> " + pageParse);
            chromeBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync(scriptToExecute);
            ExtractLinksFromWebPage(await GetHtmlAsncAsync(chromeBrowser), word, "google.com");
            await SearchEngineDelay(5000);
        }

        if (pageCount == pageParse)
        {
            continue;
        }

        BtnFindPotentialLinks.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

So `GetKeywords();` would contain a few keywords formatted like: `word1|word2|word3` etc I then split them and attempt to loop in Google 7 times (each keyword) once that has happened:

We then hit `if (pageCount == pageParse)` ideally once the 7 searches count is up repeat the process with the next word in the array list `foreach (string word in words) {`.

I thought using `continue;` would do that, it would carry on to the next item in the array and start the process again, but it does not seem to it just stops on the last page, and doesn't re-enable the button.

I know from debugging the counter is hit as expected, the code could be written better, i planned to do this once this issue was fixed, any suggestions on what I have done wrong is appreciated.

Comment: /me removed some useless spaces...... You, as a 5 year SO enthousiast, should have done that yourself!

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're trying top do, but you are not resetting `pageCount` for each word. So it equals 6 after the first word, and keeps incrementing for each additional word, so it never equals 6 again. Plus you're only skipping one line by continuing.

Comment: Hmm, on the last iteration of your loop, if `pageCount == pageParse` is `true`, then the rest of the code in that iteration of the loop won't execute. You will leave the loop and you won't hit `BtnFindPotentialLinks.Enabled = true;`

Comment: I cannot make any sense of the posted code. The `pageCount == pageParse` if-statement just looks incorrect to me, for the already posted reasons. But the only reason you should exit the loop early should be if you hit the return or get an exception. Note that your not removing empty entries when splitting the string, so `word` might very be empty or whitespace. I would advice more through debugging.